# Remove dynamically added css files reference from vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a web form with master page, upon page load the css files references gets added dynamically from the app_theme folder. My requirement is to remove these dynamic references, for this i am using the following c# code

```
var themePath = string.Format("~/App_Themes/{0}", Page.Theme);
var removeCandidate = Page.Header.Controls.OfType<HtmlLink>().Where(link => link.Href.StartsWith(themePath)).ToList();
removeCandidate.ForEach(Page.Header.Controls.Remove);
```

This code works fine. Now when  i try to use this same code in vb.net (asp.net 2.0) by converting the above c# code to vb through online c# to vb converters it gives compilation error. Can anyone help me with equivalent code to the c# code provided in vb.net (asp.net 2.0)

Comment: My vb is really rusty so this is just an educated guess (note //// denotes new line): `Dim removeCandidate = Page.Header.Controls.OfType(Of HtmlLink).Where(Function(link)  link.Href.StartsWith(themePath)).ToList() //// removeCandidate.ForEach(AddressOf Page.Header.Controls.Remove)`